# Parse Bash to Python

Tags: python, bash, parsing, parse-tree

I want to parse a Bash script and turn it into a Python script (convert text which represents a valid bash script to text which represents an equivallant python script).
How do I get started? any previous work, recommended blogs / articles / books?

Comment: Do you want to convert one particular Bash script or is your ambition to design a general Bash to Python converter?

Comment: design a general bash to python converter

Comment: It is impossible in general, see my answer

Answer (score 2):

If you think about it, *in general*, a unix shell script cannot be parsed into some [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) because shells don't work this way (they are essentially expanding strings into other strings). Bash is [working](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Operation.html) by tokenizing then [expanding](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html) things.

For instance, think of what

```
mycd=cd
myexit=exit
$mycd /tmp
ls
$myexit 23
```

is doing

So in practice, you need to understand what your particular shell script is doing, and rewrite it in Python.

You could read some general textbooks on compilation, e.g. the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools)

So a general Bash to Python converter is practically impossible (at most, you'll write a sort-of-bash shell interpreter in Python)

Theoretically a [Post rewriting system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_canonical_system) is [Turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) and the [Halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) is unsolvable (hence the intuition that a *generic* Bash to Python compiler cannot exist, otherwise as some uninteresting shell interpreter in Python).

You could however take some heuristic approach and spend a lot of time building a converter using various heuristics. But the general case is still equivalent to a shell interpreter in Python. I'm not sure it is worth the effort.

See also Yann Regis-Gianas FOSDEM2018 [talk *Parsing POSIX [S]hell*](https://archive.fosdem.org/2018/schedule/event/code_parsing_posix_s_hell/)

Comment: It's incorrect to say that you can't parse a shell script. Nothing about your example is beyond the capabilities of a hobby compiler. Just a dynamic language with an implementation of an `eval` function

Comment: Just added an interesting reference to answer your comment

Comment: Yes, it's not easy to parse the full sh syntax. It's not even reasonably hard. Never the less, it's possible (which is my only gripe with your answer). While you probably can't do it with Yacc, you can definitely do it with parser-combinators. Yann himself created a parser for `sh`

Comment: I have *no* clue how the fact that a Post rewriting system being Turing complete, thus subject to the halting problem means that a general bash to Python converter is impossible to write. What does that actually mean, concretely? That if I write a converter it either won't be perfect or will be perfect but might get stuck in an infinite loop? And is this Post rewriting system really relevant here, a converter would be working with ASTs in a turing complete language and stuff, not this specific system of transformation rules stored as tuples.

Comment: Basile, can you please educate me on this? How can it be that converting one programming language to another one is theoretically impossible? I can come up with some trivial "programming language" that could easily be converted to Python (lets say Python but you can also use `///` to start a comment), so there must be some sort of continuum of what can and can't be converted? I've been thinking about this and I don't understand how your argument makes any sense. I can see this being true if we have to handle invalid programs as well, but surely you can convert an AST into another AST

Comment: This is interesting to me because I work on [curlconverter](https://curlconverter.com), which rewrites Bash commands in other programming languages, including Python.